# Jquery Get Textarea.val() with newlines

Tags: jquery, asp.net, newline

I need to get the text entered into textarea and detect newlines (preferably `<br>`). I traced it until serverside and am sure that there are newlines because I'm printing the value with `.val()`. On serverside, I access to the same controls value and I see no newlines. I'm starting to think that '\n's don't appear on server side. I really don't want to replace all newlines with a character.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get NewLines in the server side:

```
string TextAreaText = txt.InnerHtml;
string ReplacedText = TextAreaText.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
Response.Write(ReplacedText);
```

Sorry for the bad format. I am very new here and am not good at formatting code. Hopefully it helps.

Hanlet

Answer (score -1):

I could guess that, if you try to render a **`textarea`** with nice format, you can see it with newline charater

```
<textarea>
</textarea>
```

So you just use: `<textarea></textarea>`.